# Xamarin.Forms PropertyChanged event does not re-calculate or re-run IValueConverter

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, inotifypropertychanged, ivalueconverter

I have a bunch of labels that I want to display for people. For example:

```
Name <value>
Age <value>
Cell <value>
Home# <value>
```

etc., but I can't guarantee that all of those fields have data in them. To compensate, I use an `IValueConverter` to look at a string, determine if it's null or whitespace, and then bind the `IsVisible` property like so:

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource gridLabel}" Text="{i18n:Translate CellPhone}"  IsVisible="{Binding CellPhone, Converter={StaticResource StringNull}}" Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
<Label Style="{StaticResource gridValue}" Text="{Binding CellPhone}" IsVisible="{Binding CellPhone, Converter={StaticResource StringNull}}" Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="Blue" Margin="0,10,0,10" VerticalOptions="Center" />
```

```
    public class StringNullOrEmptyBoolConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {            
            if (value != null)
            {
                string s = value.ToString().Trim();
                return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s);
            }
            return false;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

My ViewModel only exposes specific fields. All of my properties are things like this:

```
public string CellPhone => _details.CellPhone;
```

So when I switch people and try to refresh the page, I tell the `ViewModel` to go through its properties and fire off `OnPropertyChanged` for each:

```
private async Task GetData()
{
    _details = await MyWebService.GetPersonDetails();

    foreach (var property in GetType().GetProperties())
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(property));
}

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

I can watch in the debugger and see all of those `PropertyChanged` events happen. But when I switch people, the labels that are hidden or not hidden remain that way. Some of those labels that were displayed no longer have data so I want to hide them, and the labels that were not displayed but have data are still invisible. I can check this for myself by taking out the Converter in the label. The data updates but the `IValueConverter` does not re-fire. I've made sure of this by setting a breakpoint. When the page is created, the first person fires them, but when I switch people, they never fire again.

What can I do to re-run all the `IValueConverter`s? I'm totally stuck.

Comment: Your converter should be more simple, something like `var s = value as string; return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s);`  i don't understand your GetData method and why you write your own Property Changed method. Also you should check if your converter is not hitting the ConvertBack method.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the speedy reply.

The GetData method goes and gets an object, which is private and in my example above it's named `_details`. The members are exposed through properties in the VM, so the VM fires PropertyChanged for each of its own properties, since refreshing the private object doesn't fire them itself. 

I just verified that it's not hitting ConvertBack at any point.

I could add a bunch of properties like `ShowCellPhone => !string.isNullOrWhitespace(_details.CellPhone)` but that seems redundant. It does work, however.

Comment: Ugh, I'm such an idiot. I changed my bindings: `Path=Detail.FieldName` and that fixed it. I didn't need to break out each property, I just needed to expose the Detail object

Comment: @DeerSteak You can have a try with rebinding data when switch people.